# Trouble emailing warnings (Jenkins Email Extension Plugin + Warnings ng Plugin)

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I would like to email a table/data from the Jenkins Warning Next Generation Plugin, but wasn't able to figure it out. I've tried looking at the documentation for [Warning Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin/blob/master/doc/Documentation.md#simple-pipeline-configuration) and [Email Extension](https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/), but wasn't sure what to do next. How could I access the variables/data in the email plugin? Is there some variable I can access like this: ${some_variable} or $SOME_VARIABLE in the "Editable Email Notification" panel? If possible, I'd like to get html from the Warnings plugin so I can display it in the email.

Comment: It seems I haven't read the documentation well enough. What I was looking for was called "tokens" and according to the documentation, you can use `${ANALYSIS_ISSUES_COUNT} `to insert the number into the email.

Comment: I m looking for the same. Please let me know in the Email notification section under which field i need to add this    ${ANALYSIS_ISSUES_COUNT}?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but if I am recalling correctly, in the field where you put the email content, you can use ${ANALYSIS_ISSUES_COUNT}

Comment: Okay thanks i ll check it.